# Unsupported method: InstantRun.getRestartDexFile() - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6
and the Gradle version in build.gradle is *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta1'*
(I updated it today only, earlier I was at gradle:2.0.0-alpha9).
Now when I try to Run my app I keep getting this  Message.

> *UnsupportedMethodException
>
>   Unsupported method: InstantRun.getRestartDexFile().
>
>   The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>
>   To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect.
>
>   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.*

Everything was running fine before the upgrade (including Instant Run).
Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer because this solved the problem for me.
I changed the classpath in *build.gradle* to

> *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3*

I did not change anything else/any setting at all, neither did I updated my Android Studio.

[Link to the page where I found it.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205073)
Had to search a lot. :)

Edit:
Alternatively as pointed out by others,
1. You can either try Upgrading Your Android Studio to 2.1.0 (OR)
2. You can try changing the *classpath in build.gradle* to

> *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0*

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same exception

> Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other
>   information from the model.

It says there is an alternative solution, so what should we do to ignore this exception ?

---

OK, upgrading the Android Studio will solve the problem.

Comment: Deepak Talan's solution did not solve my problem but updating studio did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I get the trouble on Android 2.1 preview 5.I changed the classpath in build.gradle to

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

update the studio to 2.1.0 , will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

first i **have android 2.1** and i have set 
     [image]

then i have set [image]

i also getting that error **Unsupported method: InstantRun.getRestartDexFile() - Android Studio**
then

## Step 1

i have **updated android to 2.2** and **get that error  Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration()** while running project to fix that issue do that

## Step 2

refer link -[Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration() while running project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591531/unsupported-method-androidproject-getplugingeneration-while-running-project)
**disable instant run**  Windows & Linux:

> Linux:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.

> Mac:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.

finally fixed all things and i ***have successfully run my project***.

Answer (score -1):

The problem solved by using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-alpha3'
```