# Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration() while running project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to run my Project with Android Studio 2.2 but I get this error

```
Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
```

I am using ButterKnife 8.4.0

My app gradle.file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

My module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Why does it not work and how do I solve it?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, what happens if you apply solutions from current answers?

Comment: @azizbekian how is that relevant

Answer (score 281, accepted):

**General Issue:-**

It can occur because AS  was checking availability of the Instant Run feature. The fixed is to disable Instant Run:

**Windows & Linux:**

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.
```

**Mac:**

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.
```

[image]

Thanks to @pophus for mentioning this.

**Use this Steps If you are using a butterknife:-**

If you are using the new Jack compiler with version 2.2.0 or newer, you do not need the 'android-apt' plugin and can instead replace apt with annotationProcessor when declaring the compiler dependency.

That is, remove

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

from your main gradle file

And remove

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

from your main module file

and replace

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

with

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Comment: I want to love instant run but it breaks things in such odd ways that it makes it impossible to use regularly without quite the time investment

Answer (score 24):

I encountered this error in Android Studio 2.2, in my case it was cause by AS checking availability of the Instant Run feature. I fixed it by disabling Instant Run:

`Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run`

Comment: Worked for my colleague. He was on gradle 1.2.3

Comment: You saved my life. I'm working on a project close to release and I don't want to upgrade gradle for it. This fix/workaround definitely helped.

Comment: @pophus it can occur due to different reason maybe instant run is one, I encountered this issue with butterknife

Answer (score 7):

Change gradle version to 2.2

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo i am infact using 2.2.0

Comment: then try by deleting your .idea folder & restart your ide. After project update to 2.2 I also faced different problems. One solution i found is to delete .idea folder. Now all are working fine.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows it is

```
File / Settings/ Build, Execution, Deployment / Instant Run.
```

Uncheck `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code...`

Comment: your answer doesn't add anything new, it has been already stated in other answers , can you clarify?

Comment: It took me some time to find this option on Windows, so I wanted to save for others this time. As simple as that

Answer (score 2):

just  **close instant run**

**Windows** 
 File -Settings- Build, Execution, Deployment - Instant Run.

**MAC** 
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.

Comment: your answer doesn't add anything new, it has been already stated in other answers , can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

I ran in the same error on a very old project. Since Android Studio 3.5 does not have the Instant Run Option anymore, I required a different solution.

It turned out, that I had to change the gradle version manually in the Project Settings. I used the version a New Project would use automatically, since the dropdowns were empty.

In my case, it was Plugin Version 3.5.1 and Gradle Version 5.4.1.

After that I started a Build - Clean Project and everything turned out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the Gradle plugin version to the last version :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

and be sure your Gradle is the last v too :

```
#Sun Nov 03 16:47:32 IRST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

NOTE: use `google` in repository too