# Rendering Problems: Unable to find the layout for Action Bar solved

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

i found solution ,and i replace new 2.3.3 as ,and use 1.0.2

all of the question render problem solved!!!

Cause the problem that IDE AS 1.0.2 use actionbar !
But as2 etc looks like OLD ACTIONBAR DEPRECIATED!

I am making an Android app and trying to use an `ActionBar`.

I am getting the following error in the log:

> UnsupportedMethodException
>                   Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration().
>                   The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>                   To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>                   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

And this error for the layout:

> Rendering Problems  Unable to find the layout for Action Bar.
>   Consider updating to a more recent version of appcompat, or switch the
>   rendering library in the IDE down to API 21 (Details)   Tip: Try to
>   refresh the layout.

When I tried reducing the SDK version to 20 or 21 it did not help.

Has anyone been able to solve this?

The details about action bar? I guess it is ,but I am not sure?

**Rendering Problems (Details)**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find the layout for Action Bar.
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:57)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:59)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:238)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:150)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you are starting a new project consider using ToolBar instead of ActionBar

Comment: `To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to` ... What version **are** you using?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'estagreen.com.funbike'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 8
        versionName '1.7'
    }

Comment: Can you share your layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsupportedMethodException Android Studio 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675848/unsupportedmethodexception-android-studio-2-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getPluginGeneration() while running project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591531/unsupported-method-androidproject-getplugingeneration-while-running-project)

Comment: I GUESS  THE PROJECT LOST

Comment: https://cloud.seu.edu.cn/gitlab/frederickjoe/aosp-frameworks-base/blame/186fe7b10f475fdccb3bcab19461bd2900347b71/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/com/android/layoutlib/bridge/bars/BridgeActionBar.java

Comment: actionbar libs ,so the problem cause me  trouble