# How to debug native react native libraries with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

This question is **NOT ABOUT how to debug the javascript-land** of an React-Native app. It is about how to debug **native libraries** (means: JAVA-Code in this case) in the node_modules-folder.

While it is very easy for me to debug native iOS-parts of RN-Applications with XCode, i stumbled upon various issues with Android Studio...
The main thing is, that the node_modules-Folder is not present after importing the project into Studio, why it is not possible to setup breakpoints to debug thru.

## Versions:

- Android Studio 2.2.2 (most recent version currently)
- react-native 0.38.0 (latest version also)
- gradle 1.3.1 (preconfigured from react-native init)
- also tried with upgrade to gradle 2.2.2
- Android SDKs and -Build Tools from up to Version 23 installed including NDK

## How I did it / Steps to reproduce

**1. create new react native project:**

```
react-native init debugTest
```

**2. install third party library with native code that you want to debug natively**

```
cd debugTest && 
react-native install react-native-sqlite-storage
```

**3. ensure that everything would work on android side:**

- launch GenyMotion
- launch an AVD
- run the application with this command in terminal:

  > react-native run-android

(this will open up packager and everything else that is needed to transfer the js-bundle).
If one wants to omit this step, it is necessary to start the packager manually:

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
```

**4. launch Android Studio**

- with the upcoming starter dialog, choose "Import Project"
- select the directory "android" of your project and click on "import"
  (these steps are taken from [official RN-documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html)):

> If you want to use Android Studio to work on native code, from the
> Welcome screen of Android Studio choose "Import project" and select
> the android folder of your app.

**5. Android Studio asks to update gradle version** from pre-configured 1.3.2 to 2.2.2. I have first denied it for the whole workflow, later on i tried it out (both did not differ significantly for me)

**6.** One have to deactivate **Instant Run** due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591531/unsupported-method-androidproject-getplugingeneration-while-running-project)

**7. Click on "Run" or "Debug"** in the Toolbar of Android Studio

So far everything works fine. I was able to set a breakpoint in MainApplication.java::onCreate and could step into this method then.

## But here are the questions:

1. The **node_modules-Folder isn't present** in Android Studio and can't be debugged this way. How to achieve that?

[image]

2. Debugging the onCreate-Method and going further down into the Java-Stack, very offen it happened that the **"Sourcecode does not match the byte code"**.

[image]

The debugger was hanging somewhere else in comments of source code but not on exactly that line, which was selected to execute.

## Android SDKs:

I have installed all SDKs and build tools and NDK and everything else since version 23:

[image]
[image]

## TL;DR:

How to debug native libraries that are present in node_modules-Folder of an react native application with Android Studio, because they are not visible in AS thus no breakpoint could be passed?

## UPDATE

Finally i've found out the root cause. For me it wasn't working due to the fact, that the library i wanted to debug, wasn't shown in Android Studio. But this was a mistake by myself because the library wasn't setup correctly, why gradle wasn't able to take notice of it.

So, this question can be used like a blog post how to do it right (and will be sufficient if the 3rd party library works out of the box with "rnpm-link" or "react-native link") [which wasn't the case here in my example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done `rnpm link` or `react-native link` ? Once you do that, there will be additional modules along with the app module, something like this. [image]

You can look at all the java code in the native module and put breakdpoints , debug etc.

Comment: How did you import the RN-project into android studio? The same way like me?

Comment: I usually just open the android folder from Android studio instead of importing. But I guess it serves the same purpose.  Have you tried to build the project  from android studio or a gradle sync, usually it prompts when something has changed in build.gradle . Shouldnt it be  `npm install react-native-sqlite-storage --save` instead of `react-native install react-native-sqlite-storage` ?

Comment: the latter one (react-native install...) is the "newer" command, including "npm install --save" (or yarn install) and react-native link, which is the modern form of "rnpm link". I tried also gradly sync manually, the folders are still not shown, but are existing in filesystem

Comment: finally i've got it... you pointed me in the right direction. Will submit the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Bam.... i can answer my first of the two questions now by myself. Thx to @agent_hunt, who put me into the right direction...

In this example application the bindings wasn't setup correctly. "rnpm link" and the newer one "react-native link", which is part of "react-native install", didn't worked correctly here for the android-part because it is not implemented in the 3rd-party-library right now, that i've used for this example.

That's why gradle didn't take notice of the library. After setting it up correctly, the folder react-native-sqlite-storage appeared in Android Studio and i was able to pass a breakpoint and to stop the execution there.

Nevertheless, debugging this library works fine, but when i wan't to step into lower/"deeper" methods of android SDK, it still has issues to point to the correct line of code *("Sourcecode does not match the byte code")*